# difference between df -h and dfc

Tags: disk-usage

Why is there a difference in the used size between `dfc` and `df -h`?

```
$ df -h
Dateisystem    Größe Benutzt Verf. Verw% Eingehängt auf
/dev/sda7        64G     51G   11G   83% /
none            4,0K       0  4,0K    0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            3,9G    4,0K  3,9G    1% /dev
tmpfs           801M    1,5M  799M    1% /run
none            5,0M       0  5,0M    0% /run/lock
none            4,0G    148K  4,0G    1% /run/shm
...

$ dfc

FILESYSTEM  (=) USED      FREE (-) %USED AVAILABLE     TOTAL MOUNTED ON 
/dev/sda7   [=================---]   83%     10.6G     63.9G /
none        [--------------------]    0%      4.0K      4.0K /sys/fs/cgroup
udev        [=-------------------]    0%      3.9G      3.9G /dev
tmpfs       [=-------------------]    0%    798.7M    800.1M /run
none        [--------------------]    0%      5.0M      5.0M /run/lock
none        [=-------------------]    0%      3.9G      3.9G /run/shm
...
```

I wouldnt round 3.9 up to 4 and then display 4,0 that makes no sense to me.

Comment: What are the actual figures (`df -k`)? Are you sure they didn't change between your two measurements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not simply "rounding".  `dfc` (and `di`) print the value rounded to the nearest representation in digits, while `df` rounds **up**.

The question does not specify a version of coreutils; I'm answering based on version 8.13 (in Debian 7), though I see the same result with 8.25.

Start with the [`-h` option](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/df.c#n1523) in `df.c`:

```
    case 'h':
      human_output_opts = human_autoscale | human_SI | human_base_1024;
      output_block_size = 1;
      break;
```

There is followup code in gnulib's "human.c" ([humblock](https://github.com/gagern/gnulib/blob/master/lib/human.c#L412)), where it decides which type of rounding to use.  Because the human-options are not modified, it uses the **ceiling** rather than *floor* or *rounding* to the nearest value.  That is because a zero happens to be the [enumeration value](https://github.com/gagern/gnulib/blob/master/lib/human.h#L49) for ceiling:

```
  /* Unless otherwise specified these options may be ORed together.  */

  /* The following three options are mutually exclusive.  */
  /* Round to plus infinity (default).  */
  human_ceiling = 0,
  /* Round to nearest, ties to even.  */
  human_round_to_nearest = 1,
  /* Round to minus infinity.  */
  human_floor = 2,
```

Comment: So this is a display Bug? Due to rounding at the wrong place?

Comment: yes - there's a lot of configurability in human.c which is not used in `df`, and rounding up (for *disk-freespace*) is definitely wrong.

Comment: Can someone fix this upstream? Or create a bug report?

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is called "rounding".

Comment: I wouldnt round 3.9 up to 4 and then display 4,0 that makes no sense to me